# a small question about python socket

Tags: python, sockets

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("XXXXX",23))
line = s.recv(10000)
```

I wonder how to show what is in the "line". I've tried print ,but what it shows is different
from what I see in python shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try `print repr(line)`... See example in http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html.